# Java HTTP POST request string not arrives

Tags: java, http, post

When I call postFile() the HTTP post is made, BUT the "request" string does not arrive to the server. The host receives the request and sends back 400 which means in this case that the request is empty.

Every example shows this should be enough.

What is the problem?

```
public static void postFile(
    String host,
    String beaconId,
    String fileName,
    String base64File)
    throws IOException {

    StringBuilder request = new StringBuilder(base64File.length() + fileName.length() + 256);
    request.append("{\n");
    request.append("\"beaconId\": \"" + beaconId + "\",\n");
    request.append("\"fileName\": \"" + fileName + "\",\n");
    request.append("\"fileContent\": \"data:application/pdf;base64," + base64File + "\"\n");
    request.append("}");

    URL url = new URL("https://" + host + "/_ah/api/service/v1/files/add");
    //TODO ignore cert problems for now!
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
        new X509TrustManager() {

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {

                return null;
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(
                X509Certificate[] certs,
                String authType) {}

            public void checkServerTrusted(
                X509Certificate[] certs,
                String authType) {}
        }
    };
    SSLContext sslContext;
    try {
        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    try {
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
    }
    catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    try {
        conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        try(OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream()) {
            os.write(request.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
            os.flush();
            int respCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String respMsg = conn.getResponseMessage();
            if (respCode != HTTP_CREATED) {
                throw new RuntimeException("HTTP error : " + conn.getResponseCode() + "\n" + respMsg);
            }
            String response = IOUtils.toString(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
            String[] lines = response.split("\n");
            if (lines.length != 6) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Invalid response : " + response);
            }
            if (!lines[2].contains("\"success\": true,")) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Post failed : " + response);
            }
        }
    }
    finally {
        conn.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

In case of application/x-www-form-urlencoded I have to use

```
    request.append("beaconId=" + beaconId + "&");
    request.append("fileName=" + URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8") + "&");
    request.append("fileContent=data:application/pdf;base64," + base64File);
```

form.